# Can we say "I am looking forward to being a doctor", or is that wrong?

Tags: grammar

Can we say "I am looking forward to being a doctor", or is it wrong like this?

Comment: Yes, if you are a medical student and you are passing your exams.

Comment: What kind of ‘wrongness’ are you concerned about?

Comment: that (being) does not work with (look forward to)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but *becoming* might be better than *being* if you mean that you are a medical student.

An actor could look forward to being a doctor in a medical drama for example.